# How to get input from ion-searchbar?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

It is super easy problem but I just can't seem to figure this out (And yes I have read the documentation).

I am trying to get the input user puts in the `ion-searchbar` **(in Ionic v4)** after they the press search and put in a const/let.

Mah HTML

```
<ion-searchbar showCancelButton="focus" class=""></ion-searchbar>
```

I don't know how I should write the TS for this.

Thanks in advance :**{**)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Use `(search)` event to call your function. This event is fired when the user will click on the search button provided by the `ion-searchbar`.
- To get the value entered in the searchbar, use `$event.target.value` which gets the value field of the tag which in this case is `<ion-searchbar>`

  ```html
  <ion-searchbar
      showCancelButton 
      searchIcon="search" 
      animated
      cancel-button-icon
      (ionCancel)="hideSearch()"
      (search)="yourSearchFunction($event.target.value)" 
      placeholder="Search Some Values">
  </ion-searchbar>
  ```

**To listen to changes as user types in the search bar:**

```
    <ion-searchbar
        ... 
        (ionInput)="yourInputChangeFunction($event.detail.value)">
    </ion-searchbar>
```

Note: On Ionic 6+, `(ionInput)` strangely emits value on `$event.target.value` although, their [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#inputchangeeventdetail) mentions `$event.detail`

Comment: $event.detail does not have the property value. The answer of Rohan Pawar works for me.

Comment: @JarmoP Thanks for pointing it out. On Ionic 6+ it looks like the value is available on `$event.target`

Answer (score 4):

In your `.html` file:

```html
<ion-searchbar
    [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.input"
    (ionInput)="updateSearchResults()"
    placeholder="Search for a place">
</ion-searchbar>
```

In your `.ts` file:

```js
export class LoginPage{

  autocomplete: { input: string; }; 

  updateSearchResults() {
     console.log(this.autocomplete.input)    //search input will display
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using `ngModel` is the easiest and more coherent way of retrieving this input value.

Comment: The ngModel value is missing the last character typed. The answer of Rohan Pawar works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this works.

`Html` file.

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-searchbar 
       debounce="1000" 
       (ionChange)="ionChange($event)">
    </ion-searchbar>
</ion-toolbar>
```

`ts` file

```
ionChange(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always Read Documentation of API, Plugins or anything which you are looking for.
You will get data by using **`ionChange() or ionInput()`**.
Use following code in HTML file

```
<ion-searchbar 
  showCancelButton="focus"  
  ionInput="getData()" 
  class="">
</ion-searchbar>
```

and in TypeScript.

```
public getData(){ 
   //ur logic here
}
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation. Also its looks like this: `(ionChange)="searchInputChanged($event.target.value)"`

Answer (score -1):

Get a reference to the searchbar using the @ViewChild directive:

View:
`<ion-searchbar #search></ion-searchbar>`

Component: 
`@ViewChild('search', {static: false}) search: IonSearchbar;`

Thereafter, get the value of the ion-searchbar as follows:

`const input = await this.search.getInputElement();
 const searchValue = input.value;`

Comment: That's not a good advice. There's many simpler ways to retrieve the value inside the searchbar without having to inject the Component and retrieve the value through the input.