# How to Implement a <ion-searchbar>in Ionic app to filter Firebase data?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

How do I Implement a Search Bar in the Ionic app to filter Firebase data? I want to implement a  to filter data as user types in. I am not able to get it done. I have seen several tutorials but still unable to achieve them. Any help will be appreciated.

this is my list.page.html

```
  <ion-searchbar (ionChange)="search($event.target.value)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list class="bg-transparent "  lines="none" *ngFor="let user of usersArrayFiltered" color="none" >
   <ion-item color="none"> <ion-card>
      <ion-card-content>
        <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{user.email}}</p>
        <p>₹ {{user.mobile}}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

this is my list.page.ts

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  UsersArray = [];
  usersArrayFiltered =[];
  constructor(
    private apiService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchBookings();
    let bookingRes = this.apiService.getUserList();
    bookingRes.snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
      this.UsersArray = [];
      res.forEach(item => {
        let a = item.payload.toJSON();
        a['$key'] = item.key;
        this.UsersArray.push(a as User);
        this.usersArrayFiltered = [...this.UsersArray];
      })
    })
  }
  search(query) {
    if (!query) { // revert back to the original array if no query
      this.usersArrayFiltered = [...this.UsersArray];
    } else { // filter array by query
      this.usersArrayFiltered = this.UsersArray.filter((user) => {
        return (user.name.includes(query) || user.email.includes(query) || user.phone.includes(query));
      })
    }
  }
  fetchBookings() {
    this.apiService.getUserList().valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Fetched users list!')
    })
  }


}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried though? I see you have a list of users with a searchbar above it, but I see no attempt at implementing a filtering feature. You're going to need to listen to input changes on the searchbar element and then filter the array based on the user query.

Comment: I actually don't know how to implement it. so i am asking for help.

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57093996/10602679

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic example. I would have two arrays – the original array `usersArray` which gets left unfiltered, and a modifiable array `usersArrayFiltered` which gets filters applied to it. You will bind to the filtered array in your HTML.

Right after you populate your `usersArray` with data in your `ngOnOnit` hook, assign `usersArrayFiltered` as a copy of the original array.

```js
// just populated usersArray
this.usersArrayFiltered = [...this.usersArray];
```

Now create a search method that takes in the search query as a parameter. If the query is an empty string, then re-assign `usersArrayFiltered` as a copy of the original `usersArray`. If it's not an empty string, then turn `usersArrayFiltered` into a filtered array of `usersArray` by only including objects that have values which contain the query string.

```js
search(query) {
    if (!query) { // revert back to the original array if no query
      this.usersArrayFiltered = [...this.usersArray];
    } else { // filter array by query
      this.usersArrayFiltered = this.usersArray.filter((user) => {
        return (user.name.includes(query) || user.email.includes(query) || user.phone.includes(query));
      })
    }
  }
```

Listen to value changes on your `<ion-searchbar>` and pass the value of it to your search function.

```html
<ion-searchbar (ionChange)="search($event.target.value)"></ion-searchbar>
```

Bind your `*ngFor` loop to the filtered array.

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let user of usersArrayFiltered">
...
</ion-list>
```

Comment: i am getting an error
 _co.search is not a function
 kindly check the OP again

Comment: Sounds like you didn't put the search function in your `list.page.ts`

Comment: @NiravJain I'm not at all trying to be harsh but if you don't know how to implement a method in a component file then you need to learn the basics of how to use Angular https://angular.io/start